# What will be the state of a UIView animation that is interrupted by the app going into the background?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

If I move a view from one position to another with animation, and put the app into the background **during** that animation, when I resume the app does it hit the completion block with `finished` being `NO`? If so, does it mean the view is somewhere between the positions, or does it force the view to be the final position when the animation's interrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `UIView` animations don't really work in a way that's intuitive to those unfamiliar with them. When you ask for an implicit animation by setting a view's frame in an animation block, the view's frame is immediately set to the new value. It is only the view's `presentationLayer` that is animated.

Testing this is behavior is very easy. Create a new single view project, turn off auto-layout for simplicity, add a button to the view, and connect that buttons action to a function like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPush:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, 0);
    if (sender.center.y < self.view.bounds.size.height/2){
        newCenter.y = (self.view.bounds.size.height - (sender.frame.size.height / 2));
    } else {
        newCenter.y = (sender.frame.size.height / 2);
    }


    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                     animations:^{
                         sender.center = newCenter;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Finished? = %@",(finished)?@"YES":@"NO");
                     }];
}
```

This code just finds out if the button is on the top or bottom half of the screen, then finds a point at the center top or center bottom and animates the button there ***very slowly***. It also logs weather or not the animation finished.

If you try out this code, hit the home button, and then re-enter the app, you'll find that the button which was animating is now at its destination.

Secondly, you'll find that the `BOOL` passed into the completion block is set to `NO` in the above case. This `BOOL` can be super handy in cases where you were planning to chain an animation. Obviously if the first animation was not allowed to complete there's a good chance you wouldn't want to kick off a subsequent one.